# How to display local ipv4 address using javascript or php or any wordpress plugins?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

i want to display ip address of my local machines in wordpress page, i try a lot plugins and code but it gives server ip address so help me out to display local machines ip .

thank you ,

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is the client's IP adress in PHP.

Comment: i tried this code but it display's server ip address..   :(

Comment: If you connect from the server, sure, because it's a client then. But if you connect to the server with your browser and echo `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` it will give you the computer's IP.

Comment: Is it only the server's IP address or is it also yours, at the same time?

Comment: when we type in cmd-> ipconfig then it display some ipv4 address .those one i want to display in my page.

Comment: ipconfig shows your own IP address.

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] is probably the one you tried

$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is the client IP adress